# On click add or remove class from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a markup that looks like the following:

```
<div class="accordion is-open">
    <h3 class="accordion-header">
        HADER
        <span class="accordion-indicator"></span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-content"></div>
</div>

<div class="accordion is-open">
    <h3 class="accordion-header">
        HADER
        <span class="accordion-indicator"></span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-content"></div>
</div> 

<div class="accordion">
    <h3 class="accordion-header">
        HADER
        <span class="accordion-indicator"></span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-content"></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to use jquery to add or remove class `.is-opened` to `div` with class `.accordion` when class `.accordion-header`

My problem is that some of the `divs` already contain class `.is-opened` and some don't. I need to be able to click and open (add class .is-opened) only that specific `div` that was clicked.

Here is my `jQuery`:

```
function accordionOpener(obj) {
    var accordionHeader = obj.find('.accordion-header');
    var accordionBody = obj.find('.accordion');
    accordionHeader.on('click',function(){
        $(accordionBody).toggleClass('is-open');
    });
}
new accordionOpener($(this));
```

I am not a big pro in jQuery, JavaScript so speak to me as if I am 10 yeas old.

Comment: I don't see any event associated with the markup. How do you invoke accordionOpener ? Have you tried : $('.accordion').on('click',function() { new accordionOpener($(this));  });

Comment: I thought that this $(accordionBody).toggleClass('is-open'); is doing it as it either opens all accordions or closes them all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic isn't quite correct. To fix this attach a click event handler directly to the `.accordion-header` class. From there you can use DOM traversal to find the related `.accordion` element and toggle the class. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.accordion-header').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.accordion').toggleClass('is-open');
  });
});
```

```css
.is-open { color: #C00; } /* this is only to see the class being added/removed */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion is-open">
  <h3 class="accordion-header">
        HADER
        <span class="accordion-indicator"></span>
    </h3>
  <div class="accordion-content"></div>
</div>

<div class="accordion is-open">
  <h3 class="accordion-header">
        HADER
        <span class="accordion-indicator"></span>
    </h3>
  <div class="accordion-content"></div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h3 class="accordion-header">
        HADER
        <span class="accordion-indicator"></span>
    </h3>
  <div class="accordion-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also thought the OP wants to close other opened divs.. not sure

Answer (score 3):

You could simple use the jQuery UI Accordion plugin: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/
simply wrap all elements in a `div` and change your headline to a `h3` tag.
You invoke the plugin like the following:

```
$('.accordion').accordion();
```

This plugin also provides keyboard access and some other accessibility features.

Comment: Yes always use the plugin built in method to do stuff.. else you'll end up with lot of custom code..

Comment: Bit wasteful to include jQueryUI in its entirety when OP may only need 3 lines of code, though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes and no. You are absolutely right jQuery UI proved a lot more. But if you are going to create a good accessible module you have to do a bit more than just applying a class to toggle it's view. You could also use a module bundler which only includes the necessary code instead of the whole jQuery UI library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to maintain only on open accordion.

```
$('.accordion').click(function(){
  $('.accordion').removeClass('is-open');
  $('.show').removeClass('show');
  $(this).addClass('is-open');
  $('.accordion-content', this).addClass('show')
})
```

In the CSS you need to specify the `.show` class and hide all other panels. I also added a cursor just for the heck of it. :)

```
.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
  display:none;
}

.show {
  display: initial;
}
```